# how to use sed/awk to remove words with multiple pattern count

Tags: sed, awk

I have a file of string records where one of the fields - delimited by ","  - can contain one or more "-" inside it.

The goal is to delete the field value if it contains more than two "-".

i am trying to recoup my past knowledge of sed/awk but can't make much headway

==========

```
info,whitepaper,Data-Centers,yes-the-6-top-problems-in-your-data-center-lane

info,whitepaper,Data-Centers,the-evolution-center

info,whitepaper,Data-Centers,the-evolution-of-lan-technology-lanner
```

==========

**expected outcome:**

```
info,whitepaper,Data-Centers

info,whitepaper,Data-Centers,the-evolution-center

info,whitepaper,Data-Centers
```

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
sed -r 's/(^|,)([^,-]+-){3,}[^,]+(,|$)/\3/g'
```

or if you're into slashes

```
sed 's/\(^\|,\)\([^,-]\+-\)\{3,\}[^,]\+\(,\|$\)/\3/g'
```

**Explanation:**

I'm using the most basic `sed` command: substitution. The syntax is: `s/pattern/replacement/flags`.

Here `pattern` is `(^|,)([^,-]+-){3,}[^,]+(,|$)`, `replacement` is `\3`, `flags` is `g`.

The `g` flag means global replacement (all matching parts are replaced, not only the first in line).

In `pattern`:

- brackets `()` create a group. Somewhat like in math. They also allow to refer to a group with a number later.
- `^` and `$` mean beginning and end of the string.
- `|` means "or", so `(^|,)` means "comma or beginning of the string".
- square brackets `[]` mean a character class, `^` inside means negation. So `[^,-]` means "anything but comma or hyphen". Not that usually the hyphen has a special meaning in character classes: `[a-z]` means all lowercase letters. But here it's just a hyphen because it's not in the middle.
- `+` after an expression means "match it 1 or more times" (like `*` means match it 0 or more times).
- `{N}` means "match it exactly `N` times. `{N,M}` is "from `N` to `M` times". `{3,}` means "three times or more". `+` is equivalent to `{1,}`.

So this is it. The `replacement` is just `\3`. This refers to the third group in `()`, in this case `(,|$)`. This will be the only thing left after the substitution.

P.S. the `-r` option just changes what characters need to be escaped: without it all of `()-{}|` are treated as regular chars unless you escape them with `\`. Conversely, to match *literal* `(` with `-r` option you'll need to escape it.

P.P.S. Here's a [reference](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html) for `sed`. `man sed` is your friend as well.
Let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: No, that removes the lines, the OP wants to remove the fields.

Comment: thanks for the quick response , just realized that the column being looked into for the pattern, can be any column and not specifically 4th column as was highlighted by my innococus records above
/yes / as Dennis pointed out , i am looking to remove the fields not the records , plus deleting any column that contains more than 2 occurences of "-" pattern

Comment: thnx a lot / a little context will help , but the problem is solved

Comment: @JungleBoy if you excuse me I'll provide a thorough explanation in about 9 or 10 hours :) it's really late in my timezone

Comment: thnx mate / appreciate the effort

Answer (score 0):

You could try perl instead of sed or awk:

```
perl -F, -lane 'print join ",", grep { !/-.*-.*-/ } @F' < file.txt
```

Comment: works / thnx - was looking forward to spend my Sunday with Sed and Awk , now will invite Perl too :)

Answer (score 0):

```
sed 's/\(^\|,\)\([^,]*-\)\{3\}[^,]*\(,\|$\)//g'
```

This should work in more cases:

```
sed 's/,$/\n/g;s/\(^\|,\|\n\)\([^,\n]*-\)\{3\}[^,\n]*\(,\|\n\|$\)/\3/g;s/,$//;s/\n/,/g'
```

Comment: how will this work if the field containing the pattern is not known

Comment: @JungleBoy: This is not specific to a particular field. The "3" repeats the the pattern enclosed in the preceding set of parentheses and, together with the following `[^,]*` will match any number of hyphens as long as there are at least 3. The overall match will match any field in the line (that's what the `\(^\|,\)` and `\(,\|$\)` do).

Comment: thnx for clarifying /got caught up in the "3" / appreciate the effort

Comment: @potong: see my edited answer for a revision which will work in more cases.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
sed 's/,\{,1\}[^,-]*\(-[^,]*\)\{3,\}//g file
```